# Merge Pandas with Filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes and I need to do a left join between them to bring the `sk_provider`, the problem is that the `description` column of the first dataframe has the values ​​separated by a slash, so the join doesn't work as expected, how can I resolve this?

First dataframe:

| sk_provider | provider |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | gmail |
| 2 | hotmail/outlook |
| 3 | ig |
| 4 | terra |
| 5 | uol/bol/zipmail |
| 6 | yahoo |
| 7 | outros |

Second dataframe:

| porcentagem | valor | provider | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100% | 664 | gmail | enviados |
| 100% | 407 | hotmail | enviados |
| 100% | 1 | ig | enviados |
| 100% | 15 | terra | enviados |
| 100% | 43 | uol | enviados |
| 100% | 74 | yahoo | enviados |

Expected output:

| porcentagem | valor | provider | type | sk_provider |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100% | 664 | gmail | enviados | 1 |
| 100% | 407 | hotmail | enviados | 2 |
| 100% | 1 | ig | enviados | 3 |
| 100% | 15 | terra | enviados | 4 |
| 100% | 43 | uol | enviados | 5 |
| 100% | 74 | yahoo | enviados | 6 |

Comment: could you provide an expected output? Also there is no `description` column in `df1`; did you mean `provider`?

Answer (score 2):

Split the strings in column `provider` of `df1` around the delimiter `/` then `explode` on `provider` and `merge` the exploded dataframe with `df2`

```
df1['provider'] = df1['provider'].str.split('/')
df2.merge(df1.explode('provider'), on='provider', how='left')
```

---

```
  porcentagem  valor provider      type  sk_provider
0        100%    664    gmail  enviados            1
1        100%    407  hotmail  enviados            2
2        100%      1       ig  enviados            3
3        100%     15    terra  enviados            4
4        100%     43      uol  enviados            5
5        100%     74    yahoo  enviados            6
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the .explode function from pandas to try and re-set your first df. This depends on your provider column being separated by a / consistantly

```
data = {
        'Column1' : [1, 2],
        'Column2' : ['gmail', 'hotmail/outlook']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['emails'] = df['Column2'].apply(lambda x : x.split('/')[0:])
df1 = df.explode('emails')[['Column1', 'emails']]
```

This will also require you to make a new df to join (df1) so be careful of that when you are performing your join.

Answer (score 1):

**2 steps:**

**step 1: create a row per provider, split by /**

```
df1['providers'] = df1['provider'].str.split('/')
df1 = df.set_index(['sk_provider'])['providers'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().drop(columns=['level_1']).rename(columns={0:'provider'})
```

result:

```
    sk_provider provider
0   1           gmail
1   2           hotmail
2   2           outlook
3   3           ig
4   4           terra
5   5           uol
6   5           bol
7   5           zipmail
8   6           yahoo
9   7           outros
```

**step 2: merge**

```
pd.merge(df2, df1, left_on =['provider'], right_on=['provider'])
```

result:

```
    porcentagem valor   provider    type    sk_provider
0   100%         664    gmail       enviados    1
1   100%         407    hotmail     enviados    2
2   100%           1    ig          enviados    3
3   100%          15    terra       enviados    4
4   100%          43    uol         enviados    5
5   100%          74    yahoo       enviados    6
```